# Can't create Azure Management Group using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bicep, azure-rbac, azure-management-groups

I'm trying to create Management Groups using the [Azure Landing Zones bicep template](https://github.com/Azure/ALZ-Bicep/tree/main/infra-as-code/bicep/modules/managementGroups) as follows:

```
az deployment tenant create --location westeurope --template-file managementGroups.bicep
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> The client 'xxx' with object id 'yyy' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/managementGroups' or the scope is invalid.

For deployment I'm using a dedicated service principal (AAD Application Registration), which has an "Owner" role assigned at the level of the "Tenant Root Group" management group.

I also tried creating a custom RBAC role with action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' and scope '/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/managementGroups' but it's invalid. It only allows the scope '/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/managementGroups/id-of-root-mg'.

What is strange is that when I execute the template using my personal account (not aad application), which also is an Owner at the "Tenant Root Group", then it works.

Answer (score 0):

At the management group level, give your service principal the `Owner` role to grant it the necessary permissions to deploy the `Bicep` template.

And also, you can create a `custom role` and assign the appropriate `permissions` as you already did. Instead of deploying it through the template or Portal, try using `Azure Powershell` as shown below.

```
$roleDef = New-AzRoleDefinition -Name "CustomRole" -Description  "xxx" -Actions "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action", "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write" -AssignableScopes  "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/<managementGroupName>" 
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName <servicePrincipalName>).Id -RoleDefinitionName "CustomRole" -Scope "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/<managementGroupName>"
```

Refer this [article](https://codingwithtaz.blog/2021/08/20/create-management-groups-and-subscriptions-with-bicep/) by *@CODING WITH TAZ* for better understanding of bicep template for creating and deploying the management groups.

> when I execute the template using my personal account (not aad application), which also is an Owner at the "Tenant Root Group", then it works.

*Regarding this issue, Check if any restrictions or firewalls are being blocked for deployments by other tenant roots in the same subscription.  Check with the administrator for the restricted privileges.*

Comment: What actually helped was assigning Owner role with az cli: 
az role assignment create  --scope '/' --role 'Owner' --assignee-object-id
It seems assigning via portal on the root management group level wasn't enough.

Comment: Yes, either CLI or PowerShell commands helps to sort out these kind of issues. @filip